# Spatial country names in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am working on a SSRS report that shows the top percent of sales for certain countries. As a result, I downloaded the map of the world, countries.shp, and linked between the analytical data set [Country] with the spatial data set [Name]. I noticed the total sales shows only in countries with full names,but doesn't show for others i.e. UK and USA as they both abbreviated! 
The question is, how do I include these two countries -USA & UK- to show up in the map?

Comment: Does the base data contain both "United Kingdom" and "UK" in the same column? If so why not include a SQL CASE statement to store occurrences  of "UK" as "United Kingdom" and similarly "USA" as "United States"?

Comment: I am using the analysis service cube as a data set. In my original data I've only got USA and UK! Can I make a switch expression in the ssrs to test if the country name is United states then USA?

Comment: Update: I used the following formula but it is not working and throws a warning =switch (Fields!Country.Value= "United States", "USA",
         Fields!Country.Value= "United Kingdom", "UK", True, Fields!Country.Value )

Comment: @Dodi81. I'm no expert on Switch. Looks like it should work! How about using a Code function where you provide the country and it returns the name. I can give you an example if you want!

Comment: I would highly appreciate it if you could show me the example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a coding method to get around your problem. You could include as many "If" blocks as you like (or  CASE statements might be better if you have a lot of country names that need changing). You would put the following...

```
=code.Get_country(field!Country.value)
```

instead of field!Country.value and adding the following in the "Code" section of the report. Access the "Code" section via the top navigation bar 
"Report>Report Properties>Code tab"

```
Function Get_country(ByRef StrCountry As String) As String
  Dim StrTemp As String
  StrTemp = StrCountry
  If StrCountry = "United States"  Then
     StrTemp = "USA"
  End If
  If StrCountry = "United Kingdom" Then
    StrTemp = "UK"
  End If
 return strtemp  
End Function
```

Comment: Yup, it worked like a charm! Thank you very very much for your help and I appreciate your valuable time :)